# ERROR:Deploying ARM-'requireGuestProvisionSignal' is not valid because the 'Microsoft.Compute/Agentless' feature is not enabled for this subscription

Tags: azure, virtual-machines, extension

I'm trying to deploy a windows server VM using ARM Template and I have configured the OS progile as below.

```
"windowsConfiguration": {
                        "provisionVmAgent": true,
                        "enableAutomaticUpdates": true,
                        "patchSettings": {
                            "patchMode": "AutomaticByOS"
                        }
                    },
                    "secrets": [],
                    "allowExtensionOperations": true,
                    "requireGuestProvisionSignal": true
```

And when i deploy getting the below error.

```
'requireGuestProvisionSignal' is not valid because the 'Microsoft.Compute/Agentless' feature is not enabled for this subscription
```

I'm stuck with this error and seeking help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove this line:

```
"requireGuestProvisionSignal": true
```

If you check the [docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.compute.models.osprofile.requireguestprovisionsignal?view=azure-dotnet) it says:

> Gets or sets specifies whether the guest provision signal is required
> to infer provision success of the virtual machine. Note: This property
> is for private testing only, and all customers must not set the
> property to false.

Comment: Hi Sam, I tried removing the property and got this error: "code": "VMAgentStatusCommunicationError",
      "message": "VM 'myVM1' has not reported status for VM agent or extensions. Verify that the OS is up and healthy, the VM has a running VM agent, and that it can establish outbound connections to Azure storage

Comment: This error indicates that the VM is unable to communicate back to Azure to register its status. Check your NSG to make sure your not blocking outbound https